# Reference to the folder of the current wix-library (wixlib)

Tags: path, wix, wixlib

how can I define File/@Source relative to the "wix-library" Project, where I am currently in?

If I use:

```
<File Id="f1" Source=".\bla"/>
```

then "." refers to the root of the calling "Windows Installer Package" Project, and for this reason can not be used!

Comment: As well as the accepted answer you can also use $(var.ProjectDir)\bla

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The variable `$(sys.CURRENTDIR)` locates to the current directory..:)

`<File Id="f1" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)\bla"/>`